# JavaScript localStorage key and value not showing in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, key, local-storage

I am using the following code written far below to set key and value in browser's localStorage. I think this code may be working because when I am using `console.log()`, values of `storageArrObj` is showing up on browser's console but the **key** and **values** are not showing up on browser's application area when I navigate to **application->local Storage** and I am using Google Chrome browser. It is supposed to show key which `storageArrObj` and its value which is  `{
            firstName: firstNameSto,
            lastName: lastNameSto
        }`

This is the full code I am using

```
<label>First Name: </label><input type="text" id="firstNameSto"><br>
<label>Last Name: </label><input type="text" id="lastNameSto"><br>
<button type="submit" id="fetchDetails">Submit and Display</button>
<div id="displayStorage"></div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('fetchDetails').addEventListener('click',storageFunction);
    function storageFunction(){
        var firstNameSto = document.getElementById('firstNameSto').value;
        var lastNameSto = document.getElementById('lastNameSto').value;
        var storageArr = [];
        var storageObj = {
            firstName: firstNameSto,
            lastName: lastNameSto
        }
        if (localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj') === null){
            storageArr.push(storageObj);
            var storeObj = JSON.stringify(storageArr);
            localStorage.setItem('storageArrObj', storeObj);
        } else {
            var parseStor = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj'));
            storageArr.push(parseStor);
            storageArr.push(storageObj);
            var storeObj = JSON.stringify(storageArr);
            localStorage.setItem('storageArrObj',storeObj);
        }
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj'));

    }
</script>
```

Comment: what happens when you run `console.log(localStorage.getItem('storageArrObj'));` when page loads or in dv tools console? Not clear if this is only a dev tools issue or code problem

Comment: I've encontered this bug before, don't know a peremnant solution, but you can close developer console, then refresh page, now open console again & in Applcation -> Locat Storage, you can see your site url, click on it, then you will see these variables!

Comment: @demonofthemist thanks, it worked !

Comment: @demonofthemist,  Thanks for your help here.  I know this is an old thread but your solution solved my issue today, 1/4/2021.  So as of this date, the issue with Chrome persists.  Hope this helps someone else.